# Referencing beans in parent application context

Tags: grails

I am trying to dynamically create a new bean instance in a Grails application with references to a number of beans that are defined in the Grails main context. The idea is to create a new bean instance based on a class provided by a plugin (generic logic) bound to an application provided data acquisition bean that is injected into the plugin supplied class.

As per the discussion in section 18.4, I'm using the BeanBuilder to programatically create a new bean with references to beans in the parent context. Based on what I've read this should work, but the references to the beans in the parent context are null (not filled by the BeanBuilder). I couldn't find any reference documentation for the BeanBuilder DSL language, so I'm not sure if I have the arguments to the "ref()" method right. I used what was in the guide documentation.

Application conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
import com.spiekerpoint.ark.kpi.finance.RevenueKpiWidget
import com.spiekerpoint.deckdemo.dashboard.RevenueKpiQuery

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    revenueKpiQuery(RevenueKpiQuery) {
        messageSource = ref("messageSource")
    }
}
```

My bean class:

```
class KpiWidget {

    MessageSource messageSource
    KpiQuery kpiQuery
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    static final String KPI_ROOT_NAME = "kpi"

    String canonicalName = "unknown"
}
```

The bean creation method (from a Grails service):

```
    Widget createWidget(String name) {

        //Get the Widget class from registrations
        Class<? extends Widget> clazz = registrations.get(name)
        if (clazz == null) {
            return null
        }

        //Instantiate the class as a bean
        BeanBuilder bb = new BeanBuilder(grailsApplication.mainContext)
        bb.beans {
            revenueKpiWidget(clazz) {
                messageSource = ref("messageSource", true)
                groovyPageRenderer = ref("groovyPageRenderer", true)
                kpiQuery = ref("revenueKpiQuery", true)
            }
        }
        ApplicationContext appContext = bb.createApplicationContext()

        //Pull the instance from new application context and return it
        Widget widget = appContext.getBean("${name}Widget")
        return widget
    }
```

I believe from the documentation that the

```
bean = ref("myBeanName", true)
```

means to search for the bean in the parent context, but I can't be sure without an actual reference for the DSL language which I could not find. I have also listed the beans in both the parent context (grailsApplication.mainContext) and my newly created context and they are all there. I have tried to reference both my own application bean and Grails supplied beans to no effect. The beans do not get injected into my new bean instance.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Is it the right way to be creating a new bean instance with support for injection of application supplied beans?

Comment: I have now determined that the injection is working as advertised. The problem was that bean class was a subclass of an abstract class, and the inherited method from the abstract class could not reference the injected values in the subclass. Clearly there is some difference for injected properties that they are not visible to superclass methods.

Presumably this is why there is support in the bean DSL for declaring abstract beans. Presumably this is also because injection is implemented using aspects and the cutting is doing something to the "normal" property inheritance.

Comment: Your question and sample code are very difficult to make sense of.  This can almost certainly be made much more simple than what you are doing here.  It looks like `registrations` must be a `Map<String,Class<? extends Widget>>` and the intent of the createWidget method is to create an instance of a `Class` retrieved from `registrations`, perform DI on that instance and return that instance.  Does that summarize the requirements?

Comment: Yes, that summarizes the requirements. I *thought* that the bean injection wasn't working, but in fact it was. The reason I thought it wasn't working is that in the actual code (not what I posted here), the Widget bean that I was instantiating was a subclass of an abstract class with methods that referenced the injected beans. In the abstract class method, the injected values are null.  I didn't notice that right away however and thought that I was using the BeanBuilder incorrectly -- I hadn't used it before. So, the solution was to declare an abstract bean hierarchy and it all worked.

Comment: If all you want to do is retrieve a class from `registrations`, create an instance of it and then assign values to the `messageSource`, `groovyPageRenderer` and `kpiQuery` property on that new instance, then you don't really need that instance to be a bean in in the context and you don't need to monkey with the `BeanBuilder` at all.  You could just create the instance yourself and then either ask the context to do DI on it, or just assign those 3 properties yourself.